# C++11 Adding a stream output operator for std::chrono::time_point

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, ostream

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
std::cerr << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << std::endl;
```

And get the following:

```
Wed May  1 11:11:12 2013
```

So I wrote the following:

```
template<typename Clock, typename Duration>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream,
  const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration> &time_point) {
  const time_t time = Clock::to_time_t(time_point);
#if __GNUC__ > 4 || \
    ((__GNUC__ == 4) && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 8 && __GNUC_REVISION__ > 1)
  // Maybe the put_time will be implemented later?
  struct tm tm;
  localtime_r(&time, &tm);
  return stream << std::put_time(tm, "%c");
#else
  char buffer[26];
  ctime_r(&time, buffer);
  buffer[24] = '\0';  // Removes the newline that is added
  return stream << buffer;
#endif
}
```

Which works, but I keep getting issues when calling this from different namespaces.  Is it correct that this should just be in the global namespace?

Comment: There is no `system_clock` in `std`. It's in `std::chrono`.

Comment: Sorry, updated with correct fix.

Comment: Note that you are doing something slightly impolite, in that you are adding an overridden operator to two types you don't "own".  What more, the next iteration of the standard might write their own `<<` overload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to be sure that the right function gets called, you should put put a `using` declaration in the scope of the code that will call it.

For example:

```
namespace pretty_time {
  /* your operator<< lives here */
}


void do_stuff() {
  using namespace pretty_time;   // One way to go is this line
  using pretty_time::operator<<; // alternative that is more specific (just use one of these two lines, but not both)
  std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now();
}
```

Comment: If I put the operator in the global namespace would it always be found?  This seems a much safe and sensible way to do it though.  Thanks.

Comment: The more C++ code I write, the less useful I find the global namespace, to be honest.  I prefer the second form `using pretty_time::operator<<` because it leaves no ambiguity for the reader.  If I wanted to make several names from the same namespace available and I was certain that no side effects would be introduced, I wouldn't be opposed to using the first form that "imports" the entire namespace, but I always like to leave a comment that points out which things I intend to use from that namespace.  Like `using namespace pretty_time; // for operator<<`

Comment: I agree.  I didn't really think about qualifying the stream operator with a using declaration.  Someone else might want to have an output of the time in another format and would conflict with my global stream operator.

Comment: Also, if you have a class/struct type that lives in a namespace, that namespace is given higher priority when resolving unqualified function names.  An example can be seen in one of my pet projects that has a type representing an IP address and provides a human readable `operator<<`.  The IP namespace [header](https://github.com/IronSavior/phlegethon/blob/master/src/net/ip.h#L49), [implementation](https://github.com/IronSavior/phlegethon/blob/master/src/net/ip.cpp#L76), and [client code](https://github.com/IronSavior/phlegethon/blob/master/src/peer_analysis.cpp#L38).  Note the lack of `using`.

Comment: I get away with not employing a using declaration because the function lives in the same namespace as the custom type that represents the ip address.

Answer (score 3):

One way to keep your mess in your own `namespace`, and avoid the somewhat impolite thing of overloading an operator on two types neither of which you own, would be to make your output syntax slightly more verbose:

```
std::cerr << pretty_print::format(std::system_clock::now()) << std::endl;
```

As follows:

```
namespace pretty_print {
  template<typename T>
  struct print_wrapper { // boost::noopy optional -- if so, use it with && as an argument
    T const& data;
    print_wrapper( T const& t ): data(t) {}
  };
  template<typename T>
  print_wrapper<T> format( T const& t ) {
    return {t};
  }
  template<typename Clock, typename Duration>
  std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream,
    print_wrapper<std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>>&& time_point)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

and access `time_point.data` to get at the raw data within your `<<` overload.

The `<<` operator will be found via ADL (argument dependent lookup) when you use a `print_wrapper<>` wrapped type, even without pulling it into the `namespace` where you use it!  To use this, you can either use `pretty_print::format(blah)` or you could `using pretty_print::format` to pull `format` into the current scope.

In effect, you have flagged the type `T` for use in your own custom set of overloads.  I like this technique of "thin typed wrappers" because it reminds me of `std::move`.

This also lets you say "I hate how `double`s are formatted", and introduce a `<<` that formats them better that takes a `print_wrapper<double>`.

As a side benefit, you can specialize/overload `print_wrapper` and `format` to take formatting arguments -- so you could `pretty_print::format( std::system_clock::now(), pretty_print::eDate::YMD )`, or `pretty_print::eFmt::compact`.